# Importing startTransition directly vs taking it from useTransition hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, react-hooks

I'm going through a course, learning Firebase, building a React app (React 18.2.0).
Got to the place where, to prevent app from crashing/freezing while setting the state, we wrap that state setting into a `startTransition()` function.

We can import this function directly from React or get it from the hook:
`const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();`

Until now, I thought that the only difference between these two approaches (also accordingly to the docs), is that:
A. We can use hook only on a top level of functional components and custom hooks
B. Using the hook gives us a convenience of `isPending` boolean that indicates if transition is still on, so it can be used to reflect it in UI.

However, if I import `startTransition` directly, it works, but taking it from the hook, with exactly same code, without using `isPending`, it doesn't, it freezes and crashes.

I tried my best finding an answer. I want to understand what am I doing wrong. Maybe because I use TypeScript, but the course doesn't, and it needs to be typed?

Here is the code of App.tsx where I comment out one approach or the other. Sorry, it's quite a few lines, `startTransition()` is on line 99, where we declare:

```
const handleEditRecipeClick = (recipeId: string) => {
startTransition(() => {
  const selectedRecipe = recipes.find((recipe) => recipeId === recipe.id);
  if (selectedRecipe) {
    setCurrentRecipe(selectedRecipe);
    console.log(selectedRecipe);
  }
});
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
```

};

Any clue will be gratefully appreciated :)

```
import {
  useCallback,
  useEffect,
  useState,
  useTransition,
  // startTransition,
} from "react";
import firebase from "firebase/compat";
import "./App.css";
import FirebaseAuthService from "./FirebaseAuthService";
import FirebaseFirestoreService, {
  queryType,
  recipeType,
  recipeWithIdType,
} from "./FirebaseFirestoreService";
import LoginForm from "./components/LoginForm";
import AddEditRecipeForm from "./components/AddEditRecipeForm";

function App() {
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();
  
  const [user, setUser] = useState<firebase.User | null>(null);
  const [currentRecipe, setCurrentRecipe] = useState<recipeWithIdType | null>(
    null
  );
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState<recipeWithIdType[]>([]);


  const fetchRecipes = useCallback(async () => {
    const queries: queryType[] = [];

    if (!user) {
      queries.push({
        field: "isPublished",
        condition: "==",
        value: true,
      });
    }
    try {
      const response = await FirebaseFirestoreService.readDocuments(
        "recipes",
        queries
      );
      const newRecipes = response.docs.map((recipeDoc) => {
        const id = recipeDoc.id;
        const data = recipeDoc.data() as recipeType;
        return { ...data, id };
      });
      setRecipes(newRecipes);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof Error) {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    }
  }, [user]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRecipes();
  }, [fetchRecipes, user]);

  FirebaseAuthService.subcribeToAuthCahnges(setUser);

  const handleAddRecipe = async (newRecipe: recipeType) => {
    try {
      const response = await FirebaseFirestoreService.createDocument(
        "recipes",
        newRecipe
      );
      fetchRecipes();
      alert(`New recipe created with ID: ${response.id}`);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof Error) {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    }
  };

  const handleUpdateRecipe = async (
    updatedRecipe: recipeType,
    recipeId: string
  ) => {
    try {
      await FirebaseFirestoreService.updateDocument(
        "recipes",
        recipeId,
        updatedRecipe
      );
      fetchRecipes();
      alert(`New recipe created with ID: ${recipeId}`);
      setCurrentRecipe(null);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof Error) {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    }
  };

  const handleEditRecipeClick = (recipeId: string) => {
    startTransition(() => {
      const selectedRecipe = recipes.find((recipe) => recipeId === recipe.id);
      if (selectedRecipe) {
        setCurrentRecipe(selectedRecipe);
        console.log(selectedRecipe);
      }
    });
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
  };

  const handleEditRecipeCancel = () => {
    setCurrentRecipe(null);
  };

  //can be more detailed here about types and constatnts, but this is simple
  //more info in button types in crwn-clothing project
  const CATEGORIES = {
    breadsSandwichesAndPizza: "Breads, Sandwiches and Pizza",
    eggsAndBreakfast: "Eggs & Breakfast",
    dessertsAndBakedGoods: "Desserts & Baked Goods",
    fishAndSeafood: "Fish & Seafood",
    vegetables: "Vegetables",
  };
  const lookupCategoryLabel = (categoryKey: string) =>
    CATEGORIES[categoryKey as keyof typeof CATEGORIES];

  //formating the date
  const formatDate = (timestamp: number) => {
    const date = new Date(timestamp);
    const day = date.getUTCDate();
    const month = date.toLocaleString("default", { month: "long" });
    const year = date.getFullYear();

    return `${day} of ${month}, ${year}`;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="title-row">
        <h1 className="title">Firebase Recipes</h1>
        <LoginForm existingUser={user} />
      </div>
      <div className="main">
        <div className="center">
          <div className="recipe-list-box">
            {recipes && recipes.length > 0 && (
              <div className="recipe-list">
                {recipes.map((recipe) => (
                  <div className="recipe-card" key={recipe.id}>
                    {!recipe.isPublished && (
                      <div className="unpublished">UNPUBLISHED</div>
                    )}
                    <div className="recipe-name">{recipe.name}</div>
                    <div className="recipe-field">
                      Category: {lookupCategoryLabel(recipe.category)}
                    </div>
                    <div className="recipe-field">
                      Published: {formatDate(recipe.publishDate)}
                    </div>
                    {user && (
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        className="primary-button edit-button"
                        onClick={() => handleEditRecipeClick(recipe.id)}
                      >
                        EDIT
                      </button>
                    )}
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
        {/* {isPending && <p>Loading...</p>} */}
        {user && (
          <AddEditRecipeForm
            //  existingRecipe={currentRecipe}
            onAddRecipe={handleAddRecipe}
            // onUpdateRecipe={handleUpdateRecipe}
            // onCancel={handleEditRecipeCancel}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If I comment out useTransition hook, and import function directly from React, it all works. As far as I understand, it supposed to be same function! I tried to implement approach with the hook, to play with extra features and to understand it better, but it didn't work even if I use just `startTransition()` without changing any code down the line